# systemd chrome remote desktop

Tags: google-chrome, systemd, remote-desktop

My systemd that controls the chrome remote desktop has a limit of 32 simultaneous users/services. To add a new one I need to stop another. Also, in several times the chrome remote desktop systemd is not activated on ubuntu boot. I've been struggling for some time to improve this

- I would like to know if it is possible to increase this limit or leave it without limit? why does this limit occur?
- To use stop, start and restart sytemd in chrome remote desktop I need sudo. Is there a way to let a non-sudo user use the chrome remote desktop systemd?

best

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @cocomac ubuntu 20.04